# mongodb cant drop index after stopping indexing

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nosql

i had to run some index on MongoDB
so i did

```
    db.devices.ensureIndex({ "installed_packages" : 1 })
```

but when it ran, i noticed it is too large and i dont have the time for it, so i stopped the indexing.

now, i need to run

```
    db.devices.reIndex()
```

but it tries again to do the index on installed_packages

i dont need it anymore, and when i try to run

```
   db.devices.dropIndex({ "installed_packages" : 1 })
```

it says :

```
{
 "errmsg" : "can't find index with key:{ installed_packages: 1.0 }",
"ok" : 0
}
```

and if i run:

```
    db.devices.dropIndex("installed_packages_1")
```

it says:

```
    { "errmsg" : "index not found", "ok" : 0 }
```

what can i do to drop it?

Comment: What does `getIndexes()` say?

Comment: it does not contain this index, but agai, the db.reIndex() is still trying to index it

Comment: How did you stop the reindex? Did you use killop: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/ ?

Comment: yes i used killop and waited until it stopped, it was between index stage 1 and 2, i saw it with db.cuurentOp()

Comment: how did you ever fixed this issue @Dima 3 years have passed Im running mongodb 3.2 and this issue still exists :/

Comment: @maumercado , i did not. never found a way to do so. just stopped using the count for the db...